# generic except clause works Exception as ex does not catch exception in python

Tags: python, exception

I have two files:
Content in **fl_fn1.py:**

```
import fl_fn2

def fn1():
    print("hi")
    try:
        fl_fn2.fn2()
    except:
        print("inside except")
    finally:
        print("finally")

fn1()
```

Content in **fl_fn2.py:**

```
import sys

def fn2():
    print("fn2")
    sys.exit(0)
```

Now when I invoke fl_fn1.py from Windows command prompt like;

> `C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\User1\Desktop\fl_fn1.py`

then my output is:

```
hi
fn2
inside except
finally
```

However when I change the exception part in fl_fn1.py to:

```
except Exception as ex:
    print("inside except")
```

Then my output is:

```
hi
fn2
finally
```

The exception part is not executed!!!
Could someone please explain what is going on. I am new to Python.

 Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SystemExit` inherits from `BaseException` not from `Exception` so to catch it you need `except BaseException as e:`. This is deliberate to prevent accidental capture of the exception via `except Exception as e:`

Comment: Oh great thanks @Chris .
I was also interested to know the different classes of exceptions, but I googled and got it!!!

https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

There some logging that will help you to understand your exception type:

```py
import sys

def fn1():
    print("hi")
    try:
        fn2()
    except:
        print("Exception type: ",sys.exc_info()[0], " occured.")
        print("Exception inherits from: ", sys.exc_info()[0].__bases__)
        print("inside except")
    finally:
        print("finally")

fn1()
```

As @Chris_Rands mentioned in his response, you receive `SystemExit` exeption which inherits `BaseException`.

Comment: Aaah thanks @andnik I learnt something new.  `sys.exc_info()[0].__bases__`